# Is it possible to disable the "Pay Via Credit Card" feature in the new SDK?

Tags: android, paypal

I'm looking over the new PayPal SDK and it appears that there is (just about) no way to configure or customize it.

I'm curious if I'm overlooking something and most specifically, if there's any way to disable the "pay via credit card" option, which takes the user into a photo app where they photograph their credit card.

Answer (score 0):

Upon some scouring I noticed this...

intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD, true);

When added to the launch intent, that will, indeed, removed the CC button from the displayed Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff here from the PayPal Mobile SDK team.

The PayPal Android SDK several extras.  Specifically, [`PaymentActivity.EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD`](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/com/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PaymentActivity.html#EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD) is there to turn off the ability to accept credit cards.  Feel free to suggest additional features on [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/).